# Simplifying iterable logic

Tags: dart

I have this code which works.  It is looping through a list of objects and getting all those where one property of the object exist in another list of objects.

```js
    List<WatchedGame> watching = List<WatchedGame>();
    for (WatchedGame watchedGame in watchedGames.list) {
      if (week.games.contains(watchedGame))
        watching.add(watchedGame);
    }
```

It seems like I could simplify this code to this.

```js
    List<WatchedGame> watching = watchedGames.list.where((watchedGame) {
      week.games.contains(watchedGame.game);
    });
```

However I get this exception.

```js
type 'WhereIterable<WatchedGame>' is not a subtype of type 'List<WatchedGame>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw in a [`toList`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) call at the end:

```
List<T> newList = list.where(condition).toList();
```

Comment: I try that and now I get "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null".

Comment: Thanks.  I think my second issue was that I needed a return statement in my condition function,  Accepting this answer.